# Show Firestore data as per the user info to disapply in the page

Tags: flutter

I have a Firestore database with travel details that capture the info travel-related and stored in the database, I have a preview button as and when the user clicks on it, it should display the info from Firestore database. I'm new to this and I tried coding like the below but it's not show the data except circular or text messages.

Also, I want to develop a customer declaration form where the user will read the policy and condition and click on check box as agreed. Please help me to solve the issue. Also, I want to develop a customer declaration form where the user will read the policy and condition and click on check box as agreed.

```
class DataShowState extends State<DataShow> {
      DataShowState();
      User? user;
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: StreamBzuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('traveldetails')
                  .doc(user?.uid)
                  .collection("travels")
                  .snapshots(),
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text("No Data");
                  // Center(
                  //   child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  // );
                }
    
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 20,
                                bottom: 5,
                              ),
                              child: Text(document['travelname'],
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your output and more glimpse of the code (where this function is called)?

Comment: And I don't think that you'd be needing that Scaffold as wrapping `Scaffold(from function call) -> Scaffold(function return)` will give out an error. Make it a container?

Comment: i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Swap `Scaffold()` for `Container()` and there's a spelling error in `StreamBuilder` which you need to rectify.

Rest code seems fine.

If you want to implement a `CircularProgressIndicator()` while the data is loading, create a if condition under builder, `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.loading` and return `CircularProgressIndicator()`

Sample code:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.loading){
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
  //... Write rest of your if statements as it is.
}
```

This should do the work. Please share voice of the file where you call `DataShow()`